# FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {}); showing error: The method 'listen' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, event-listener

`FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {});`

The method 'listen' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'listen'.

Above code line showing error: The method 'listen' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.

Right now I am searching in Firebase is there was any updates!

Comment: Can you try using flutter clean. Because Stream comes from dart itself. Rather than firebase

Comment: @KrishBhanushali that work, after i tried many times flutter clean